# error of compiling and linking example C propgrams in an open source tool (SCIP) in cygwin32 on win7

Tags: c, windows-7, cygwin, .a, scip

This is not a programing question but a tool (SCIP) install and library "mismatch" problem on cygwin 32 on win 7.

If you do not think this is a good place to ask this, please let me know before voting down. thanks !

I am trying to install a integer  programming  model solver from

```
http://scip.zib.de/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-3.1.1.tgz
```

This can be used to solve optimization  integer  programming problems.

It support installing on cygwin 32 bits.

I have installed it successfully because I can launch the interactive shell from cygwin like :

```
$ ./bin/scip
SCIP version 3.1.1 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode: optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 2.0.1] [GitHash: bade511]
Copyright (c) 2002-2014 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik Berlin (ZIB)

External codes:
  SoPlex 2.0.1         Linear Programming Solver developed at Zuse Institute Berlin (soplex.zib.de) [GitHash: 51184cf]
  cppad-20140000.1     Algorithmic Differentiation of C++ algorithms developed by B. Bell (www.coin-or.org/CppAD)

user parameter file <scip.set> not found - using default parameters

SCIP>
```

But, I am trying to find out how to call its API library (implemented by C)  from C++ or C# by studying its example code  in the tool.

After downloading, the example code can be found at

```
SCIP\scipoptsuite-3.1.1\scip-3.1.1\examples
```

When I followed the INSTALL instructions (in each example subfolder) by running

```
make all
```

I got error:

```
/examples/Binpacking
$ make all
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/branch_ryanfoster.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/cmain.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/cons_samediff.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/pricer_binpacking.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/probdata_binpacking.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/reader_bpa.o
-> compiling obj/O.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt/vardata_binpacking.o
-> linking bin/binpacking.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt.spx

**../../lib/libsoplex.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Makefile:143: recipe for target 'bin/binpacking.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt.spx' failed
make: *** [bin/binpacking.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt.spx] Error 1
```

Why the static lib format cannot be recognized ?

I have asked this in SCIP mailing list, but, nobody knows how to solve this kind of IT issue (compile/link).

So, hope that I can get help here.

If more information needed, please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: did you install the SCIP package?  There is a top level directory that contains a INSTALL file, several .tgz files, a makefile, a makefile.doit   This INSTALL file tells how to install the package.  It will not install correctly by jumping to the examples directory and trying to install the examples until after the main/top level install has been executed with no errors

Comment: @user3629249, yes, I have installed it successfully.